# How do I adjust the page title for different Section and Entry pages?

Tags: templating, titles

Inside the default template that comes installed with Craft, the title of a page is set as:

```
<title>{% if title is defined %}{{ title }} - {% endif %}{{ siteName }}</title>
```

This works perfectly for the homepage and on pages where the {{ title }} variable is set. However for individual entries inside a channel, only the site name is used for the title.

I've tried to use the {{ entry.title }} variable instead, however in that case the title of the homepage is rendered as 'Homepage - {{ siteName }}'.

What's the best way to achieve the following page titles for the different sections?

```
Homepage: {{ siteName }}
Page: {{ title }} - {{ siteName }}
Entry: {{ entry.title }} - {{ siteName }}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `title` var can be set in the child templates, that way you can fine-tune it for each section of your site.

Take a look at these default templates:

**news/index.html:**

```
{% set title = "News" %}
```

**news/_entry.html:**

```
{% set title = entry.title %}
```

**_layout.html:**

The main layout just checks if it has been defined or not:

```
{% if title is defined %}{{ title }} - {% endif %}{{ siteName }}
```

.

P.S. Embed templates might be confusing at first, but are really great, [check out the docs.](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html)